# i can't kill multiprocessing or threading in python when try to run airodump

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, aircrack-ng

I try to run Airodump-ng Wlan0mon in python code using Threading 
or Multiprocess but i can't kill the process 
i try all solution in this site but it not work
my code is

```
def RubAirdump():
 try:
     def ai():
      global Airdump
      Airdump = subprocess.Popen(["airodump-ng {}".format(CheckModeMonter())], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,preexec_fn=os.setsid())
     airo1 = threading.Thread(target=ai)
     airo1.start()
     time.sleep(5)
     print(Airdump.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
 except Exception as EXC3:
     print("[-] There is some Error that say", EXC3)
     sys.exit()
```

i'm trying to use (os.kill) and (os.killpg) but its not work
all i wan't is to make airodump run for 5 or 10 second then 
stop get the result printed and returned by this fuction

checkModeMonter() is returned to me wlan0mon

I want any way to do this ,,
thanks

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/1132603 as you have shell=True and might be running the same problem

Comment: @Totoro i't not work

Comment: also prexec_fn should be a function and you are executing the function before, try without the parenthesis, you can also pass start_new_session=True (check note in Popen method) instead if the python version has it.

Comment: @Totoro I'ts also not work

Comment: there are more answers on th elink I provided like https://stackoverflow.com/a/13143013/1132603, check what works

Comment: @Totoro it is solved by using communicate(timeout=5) ,thanks for helping

Comment: Good to know. That was the last one :). please give the person that provided the hint/solution an upvote

Answer (score 0):

it is solved by using communicate(timeout=5)

Comment: Great work solving your problem. Please consider elaborating more on the problem and solution in your answer to help others who come across it.